# How to put a launch file?

Tags: ros, laser, roslaunch, hokuyo, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.

I'm trying to create a launch file as part of Hokuyo TF.

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_to_base_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom base_link 100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="US6" args="0 7 2 1.5708 0 0 base_link laser 100" />
</launch>
```

Credits to Malefitz for the codes.

However, I'm wondering where should I copy the .launch file to.

Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211603/how-to-put-a-launch-file?/) by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Put launch files into the package you pass as the 1st argument.

```
$ roslaunch [package] [filename.launch]
```

As [noted in the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch#Using_roslaunch), roslaunch command automatically looks into the passed package and detect available launch files.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-06-17**:
Thanks! I got it!